# WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I want to inject my ejb "ProfileEJB" into my jsf managed bean "SampleController" like so:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ProfileEJB {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Profile create(Profile p) {
        em.persist(p);
        return p;
    }

}
```

SampleController:

```
@Named(value = "sampleController")
@ViewScoped
public class SampleController {

    @Inject
    private ProfileEJB profileBean;

    public SampleController() {
    }

}
```

The problem is i get the following error:

```
CDI deployment failure:WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ProfileEJB] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.example.controller.SampleController.profileBean]. Possible dependencies [[Session bean [class com.example.ejb.ProfileEJB with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [ProfileEJB], Session bean [class com.example.ejb.ProfileEJB with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [ProfileEJB]]]
```

I can understand from the message that there are two same beans and it cannot decide which to inject but i don´t know why there are two same beans? Can someone please explain it to me?
Thank your very much!

Comment: How is your app deployed?

Comment: its deployed on glass fish 4.0 and packaged as a ear. it is a maven enterprise application project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future searching for a solution: moving from Glassfish 4.0 to 4.1 solved the problem. Don´t ask me why

Comment: Not my case, I have the same issue and my application runs on Glassfish 4.1. Has the other answer solved the problem?

Comment: No but i switched long time ago from Glassfish to Wildfly. Much faster and better ;)

Answer (score 1):

EJB and CDI are two different realizations of context and dependency injection concept. And you must be very carefully when have deal with it together. I see in error string that Glassfish "think", that Stateless bean is CDI bean too, but hold definition of them in two separated baskets.

Try to replace `@Inject` annotation to `@EJB`. I suppose its solved the problem.