# CDI error: Ambiguous dependencies trying to inject EntityManager

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, entitymanager, jboss-weld

I'm facing a strange error while trying to deploy my EJB 3.1 application in a JBoss 7.1.1 application server: `WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject public br.com.sigga.siot.dao.masterdata.impl.ProfileDAOImpl(EntityManager)]. Possible dependencies [[Resource Producer Field [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceContext @Produces private br.com.sigga.siot.cdi.JPAProducer.entityManager], Resource Producer Field [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceContext @Produces private br.com.sigga.siot.cdi.JPAProducer.entityManager]]]`

As you can see, the "possible dependencies" points twice to the same `EntityManager` producer: `br.com.sigga.siot.cdi.JPAProducer.entityManager`. This field is declared as follows:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "siotMobility")
@Produces
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

A similar case was related in [WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328163/weld-001409-ambiguous-dependencies) but I cannot change my application server to Glassfish 4.1. :-)

My development environment: Eclipse Luna, Java 7, Maven 3.x (eclipse's embedded version). I have one Maven project (siot-mobility) with 3 modules (siot-mobility-[ear|ejb|web]).

The EAR module's POM declares the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.sigga</groupId>
        <artifactId>siot-mobility-web</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.sigga</groupId>
        <artifactId>siot-mobility-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Maven EAR plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <version>6</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>br.com.sigga</groupId>
                <artifactId>siot-mobility-web</artifactId>
            </webModule>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>br.com.sigga</groupId>
                <artifactId>siot-mobility-ejb</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Feel free to ask me about any more info that could help you help me. :-) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error found: the EJB module was present twice in the generated EAR, once on the root path of the EAR file and a second time in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the WAR file.

I changed the dependency declaration in the WAR project's POM file from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.com.sigga</groupId>
    <artifactId>siot-mobility-ejb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.com.sigga</groupId>
    <artifactId>siot-mobility-ejb</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This way, the EJB module is not copied to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the WAR file and I have only one `EntityManager` producer in the generated EAR file.